# compute total days work using query from vb6 to msaccess

Tags: sql, database, vb6, ms-access-2007

I am making a payroll system using vb6 with ms access as database. I have 3 tables in ms access namely:

```
tblemployee,   tblattendance,   tblpayroll
```

I want to get the payroll of all employees for the month of ex april, year 2013. All these datas will be from tblattendance.

Ex. (Some fields are hidden)
tblattendance:

```
        Empid  Day  Month  Year  totalhourworkfor1day  
        1      1    april  2013  8
        2      1    april  2013  5
        1      2    april  2013  8
        2      2    april  2013  5
```

tblpayroll:

```
        empid  month  year  Totalhoursworkfor1month
        1      april  2013  16
        2      april  2013  10
```

After querying for the month of april year 2013, all the totalhourworkfor1day for 1 employee will be added and the result will save in to Totalhoursworkfor1month.

How to do this? Considering that from my vb6, I only need to select the month and year to generate the payroll and after it will display to the listview

Tried code:

```
insert into tblpayroll(empid,month,year,hourswork)
select id,month, year, sum(hourswork) from tblattendance where empid=id group by empid;
```

Comment: Yup, I have tried codes but these are far from right one. I did not post my codes because I know these are very wrong..

Comment: Already posted my code. I'm still a beginner, haven't really tried when it comes to deeper coding in sql.

Comment: Yup I've already know how to run queries whatsoever in vb6, only how to make queries, build, create queries. Having hard time especially when it needs much more understanding and analyzing queries.

Comment: I see. You posted expected results -- that's great. Could you please also post what's wrong with the results you get from the code you tried?

Comment: Errors..tried to fix, no result, later error comes..It always goees like that.

Comment: I have the same problem with this. Hope I could find answers.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?
The dates are just one field. I have used the MinOfWorkDay so as to avoid complications with months ending on 28,29,30,31. But this can be worked around if you want to have "month ending". In any event you could format results to simply show the month/year.

It could further enhanced by the HAVING clause defaulting to the month just ended, or using "from" and "to" dates entered on a form.

```
INSERT INTO tblPayroll ( Empid, HoursWorked, MonthEnd )
SELECT tblWork.Empid, Sum(tblWork.WorkHours) AS SumOfWorkHours, Min(tblWork.Workday) AS MinOfWorkday
FROM tblWork
GROUP BY tblWork.Empid
HAVING (((Min(tblWork.Workday)) Between #4/1/2013# And #4/30/2013#));
```

I'd be pleased to give more help if you come back with more questions.

15 Apr: I boobed! I assumed you would be processing your data in MS Access. I don't know vb6 so can't help any more. Could your whole project be done in access?

Comment: Is this also applicable if i only select month and year from my vb6 ? If so, do I have to convert my "month" to its correspondinng 'monthnumber" ? Using your code, what should I select from my vb6 for I am able to run this?

Comment: You save the above SQL statement in a MS Access query, then you just run the query from VB6. But VB6 / MS Access is overkill. Pretty much everything you do in VB6 you can do in MS Access so why don't you just keep it one platform to keep it simple.